# Hybrid optmistic / pessimistic locks

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

### The application

Hi,

We have an application (J2EE/Hibernate/JPA) with several users making actions on a **common entity**.

To simplify, let's say this application is like **Google docs** :
A **shared document** on which **many users** can update at the same time.

We have chosen optmistic lock to handle concurrency :

- Sentences are **separate entities**
- There is a **low chance** that several users will update the **same sentence** at the **same time**
- In that case, it is ok for one of the user to **receive a message** "sorry another user tried to edit the same sentence"

### Background processes

So far, so good.

But now, we have added **background processes** (quite fast ones) to this application.
They **regularly** make changes (let say it replace any occurence of a word by another).

It is **ok for those job to fail**. Their task is not urgent, and they can try the same task the next time (10 seconds after).

The problem with the optimistic lock in that situation is that now a single user cannot perform anymore **long actions** on te **whole document**.

Indeed, if a user changes the font of the whole document (on all sentences), and this **action takes a while** (> 10 sec), then in the meantime the background process will **change some words**, and the longer action (= the user action : change font) will fail on concurrent access.

**This is not acceptable** to show this mesage to the user : "Your action failed because some technical process was running at same time".

And since the background process could **retry later**, we would rather have it fail.

## The question

How do we setup **pessimistic lock for some actions** / actors , within a optimistic lock approach ?

## Potential solutions

In order to keep the optimistic approch for the users, we have thought of the following solution :

- Create a "**user action**" flag, that would be set during any action of any user
- A job will not start until this flag is "off"
- At the end of any running **processes**, check if the flag is on : If so, cancel this action / rollback.

This way, the **processes** will only be able to run at idle time, while the user is not doing anything.

## Help

Is this a good approach ?
We could not find any article / discussion about good practices for hybrid types of locks.

Answer (score 1):

For the "document" it is the typical case of **read-write lockings**.

A read-write lock works so, that multiple readers can lock the resource parallelly, but only one writer. Because of this, readers and writers are mutually exclusive.

Your real users would put a "read" lock to the document, when they start to edit. More than one of them can enter at the same time, each of them will edit a different sentence.

Your background process is the writer in this case, it can enter (by putting a "write" lock) if no readers (and no other writers) are locking this document. Then the background process can do its changes.

Also, it may happen that a user fails to open the document, but - since the background process is fast - it is very unlikely (and it's temporal, you can retry 1 sec later, even without notifying the user).

To provide you some reference, here's how you can use `LockModeType.READ` and `LockModeType.WRITE` in JPA: [Read-Write lockings in JPA](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Read_and_Write_Locking)